# Atomicity of optimistic locking

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I use Oracle 11g (it may have impact on solution). I have versioned table like below. I want make atomic operation consisting of select from this table, insert to another table (depending on state of former) and updating state of former table.

I want simple solution (simple problem simple solution?), atomic and I want to avoid deadlocks. I choose optimistic locking strategy.

So, I have such table

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id int,
    version int,
    state varchar(20)
);
```

In pseudocode I have something like this:

```
Line 1: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
Line 2: START TRANSACTION;
Line 3: SELECT state as S, version as V from table where id = X;
Line 4: if (S == 'TODO') then 
Line 5:     INSERT INTO other_table ...
Line 6:     UPDATE table SET state = 'DONE', version = version + 1 WHERE id = X and version = V
Line 7: COMMIT;
```

As far I understand SQL transactions, another thread can execute the same code block between 6th line and 7th of first tread. And then (considering isolation level = read committed) I have two inserts to `other_table` which I don't want to.

How can I make this code block really atomic?

I'd like to avoid locking rows and serialization isolation level (deadlocks).

Comment: If your dbms uses optimistic concurrency control you'll never get any deadlocks. A transaction is an atomic operation.

Comment: Do you have a particular RDBMS in mind?

Comment: Yes, it's Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to mess with isolation level, you can do the `UPDATE` first and if the update was successful, do the `INSERT`. The update will lock the affected row ([oracle documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502)), so another session will be blocked until the first session closes its transaction.

Example with PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE t
     SET state = 'DONE', version = version + 1
   WHERE id = x
     AND state = 'TODO';

  IF( SQL%FOUND ) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'INSERT HERE' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hm.. Are you sure that update locks the affected row until end of transaction? Can you share some link to documentation?

Comment: Sure, have a look at [Automatic Locks in DML Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502). You can also try it yourself by executing the code in two SQL*Plus sessions without closing the transaction.